# Does systemd-networkd / systemd-resolved add search domains specified in DHCP?

Tags: dns, dhcp, systemd

I'm using systemd-networkd and systemd-resolved to manage my network configuration and DNS resolution. I thought it would include search domains specified by the DHCP server, but it doesn't appear to.

```
# /etc/systemd/network/wlan0.network
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

The DHCP server response includes "Option: (15) Domain Name" (I've checked with wireshark), and I've also tried adding "Option: (119) Domain Search", but nothing I've tried results in a "search" line being added to the resolv.conf file:

```
# /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
...
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver fe80::...
```

I know I can specify `Domains=....` in the `wlan0.network` or `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, but I would expect systemd would respect the DHCP options.

I've restarted the network system and confirmed `/etc/resolv.conf` is properly symlinked:

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload && sysetmctl restart systemd-networkd && systemctl restart systemd-resolved
$ ll /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Oct  4  2017 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
$ pacman -Qi systemd | grep Version
Version         : 243.51-1
```

Comment: There's `UseDomains=` under `[DHCPV4]` and `[IPV6ACCEPTRA]`. See `systemd.network(5)`. Btw the latest recommended mode of operation for systemd-resolved is to symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` to `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UseDomains=true` option as suggested in the comment but depending on the version of systemd you were using this would probably not be sufficient. I guess you were hit by the systemd's issue [#8174](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8174) – *systemd-networkd DHCP search domains option* which was [fixed](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/0f44806d8e1e0a8348d6c28951b0ed0b4cae963a) on July 14th 2019 and released in version [243](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/releases/tag/v243) of systemd on September 3rd 2019.

The issue was described as follows:

> I expected that by enabling [DHCP]: UseDomains=true in network
>   configuration, the DHCP client would use DHCP provided search domains.
>   The client only uses DHCP provided search domains if the server
>   specifies this option as "forced"

By the way, I highly recommend asking Linux specific questions at https://unix.stackexchange.com